# Evaluate/Compare multiple numerical dataset for consensus or difference in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-visualization

I have a couple of stacked histograms which I need to compare/evaluate for similarity or difference.

[image: Stacked histogram generated from one dataset]

I believe rather than evaluating histograms is will be east to work with dataset used to plot these stacked histograms, which is in format:

```
RED                PURPLE       BLUE        GREY       YELLOW

22.0640569395   16.9483985765   0   60.987544484    0

8.1850533808    8.8523131673    0   82.962633452    0

6.8505338078    6.8950177936    0.756227758 85.4982206406   0.5338078292

6.7615658363    5.2491103203    1.6459074733    86.3434163701   0.6672597865

5.8274021352    7.384341637 2.1352313167    84.653024911    1.1565836299

7.8736654804    6.628113879 1.5569395018    83.9412811388   1.2010676157

7.1619217082    8.1850533808    1.2455516014    83.4074733096   1.3790035587

5.5604982206    10.2758007117   1.0676156584    83.0960854093   1.0231316726

7.1174377224    7.6067615658    0.7117437722    84.5640569395   0.756227758

7.8736654804    3.9590747331    0.6672597865    87.5    0.3113879004

7.6512455516    7.8736654804    0.5338078292    83.9412811388   0.5338078292

7.6067615658    8.9857651246    1.4679715302    81.9395017794   0.3558718861

8.9412811388    8.0071174377    1.3790035587    81.6725978648   0.5782918149

19.0836298932   9.2081850534    2.1352313167    69.5729537367   1.3790035587

14.9911032028   11.0765124555   3.2028469751    70.7295373665   1.0676156584

15.3914590747   10.8985765125   3.024911032 70.6850533808   1.2900355872

17.4822064057   12.5444839858   2.4911032028    67.4822064057   1.334519573

15.8362989324   13.0338078292   2.0017793594    69.128113879    1.334519573

17.037366548    10.4537366548   2.4021352313    70.1067615658   1.2010676157

20.2846975089   10.0088967972   0   69.706405694    1.0676156584

28.7366548043   12.6334519573   0   58.6298932384   0
```

Is there any possible way I can compare such dataset from multiple experiments (n=8) and visually show (plot) that these datasets are in consensus or differ from each other? Can QQplot be used to evaluate such datasets.

Awaiting reply,

Atul

Comment: possibly better on cross validated?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you also posted this to the R-help list and cross posting is generally frowned upon.  One way to look at the data would be to plot separate lines for each variable.  If the distributions were identical, one would expect the lines to overlap.  First, here is your data in a more easily used format (just cut and paste into R):

```
dat <- structure(list(RED = c(22.0640569395, 8.1850533808, 6.8505338078, 
6.7615658363, 5.8274021352, 7.8736654804, 7.1619217082, 5.5604982206, 
7.1174377224, 7.8736654804, 7.6512455516, 7.6067615658, 8.9412811388, 
19.0836298932, 14.9911032028, 15.3914590747, 17.4822064057, 15.8362989324, 
17.037366548, 20.2846975089, 28.7366548043), PURPLE = c(16.9483985765, 
8.8523131673, 6.8950177936, 5.2491103203, 7.384341637, 6.628113879, 
8.1850533808, 10.2758007117, 7.6067615658, 3.9590747331, 7.8736654804, 
8.9857651246, 8.0071174377, 9.2081850534, 11.0765124555, 10.8985765125, 
12.5444839858, 13.0338078292, 10.4537366548, 10.0088967972, 12.6334519573
), BLUE = c(0, 0, 0.756227758, 1.6459074733, 2.1352313167, 1.5569395018, 
1.2455516014, 1.0676156584, 0.7117437722, 0.6672597865, 0.5338078292, 
1.4679715302, 1.3790035587, 2.1352313167, 3.2028469751, 3.024911032, 
2.4911032028, 2.0017793594, 2.4021352313, 0, 0), GREY = c(60.987544484, 
82.962633452, 85.4982206406, 86.3434163701, 84.653024911, 83.9412811388, 
83.4074733096, 83.0960854093, 84.5640569395, 87.5, 83.9412811388, 
81.9395017794, 81.6725978648, 69.5729537367, 70.7295373665, 70.6850533808, 
67.4822064057, 69.128113879, 70.1067615658, 69.706405694, 58.6298932384
), YELLOW = c(0, 0, 0.5338078292, 0.6672597865, 1.1565836299, 
1.2010676157, 1.3790035587, 1.0231316726, 0.756227758, 0.3113879004, 
0.5338078292, 0.3558718861, 0.5782918149, 1.3790035587, 1.0676156584, 
1.2900355872, 1.334519573, 1.334519573, 1.2010676157, 1.0676156584, 
0)), .Names = c("RED", "PURPLE", "BLUE", "GREY", "YELLOW"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

Now we can setup to plot the data.  I like `ggplot2` so I use that package, but you could do this in any.

```
## create row index
dat$x <- 1:21

## load packages
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

## melt the data frame to be long, long dat, ldat for short
ldat <- melt(dat, id.vars="x")

## plot the distributions
ggplot(ldat, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

(Image here, but I cannot post images yet)

Looking at this, the variables really do not look like they are on the same scale.  We can still reasonably assess their distributions, but it is a bit trickier because they could move together but just with very different means, causing it to be difficult to see fluctuation in (for example) the bottom two.  One possible solution is to scale the data.

```
## scale the data first to have equal mean and variance
dat2 <- as.data.frame(scale(dat))
## remake index so it is not scaled
dat2$x <- 1:21

ldat2 <- melt(dat2, id.vars="x")
ggplot(ldat2, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

(Image here, but I cannot post images yet)

Finally, it is a bit strange to have colour names that do not match the actual colours used.  We can fix this by adding a manual colour scale based on the levels of the factor `variable` which are just the names (which are colours).  I also increased the line size slightly.

```
ggplot(ldat2, aes(x, value, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1.25) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = levels(ldat2$variable))
```

This gives the final result:

(Image here, but I cannot post images yet)